# how to avoid onCreate call by onConfigurationchange

Tags: android, android-intent

`onCreate` is called by `onConfigurationChange` .There are two activities : `FirstActivity` starts `SecondActivity`. But `SecondActivity`, which is a native activity and the expected behavior when I press home key from `SecondActivity` will exit from the app. Currently, in `SecondActivity`  `onConfigurationChange` call `onCreate`.

```
A->B
```

In activity A, I am using this code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Log.i("Search Activity", "onCreate() was called.");
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

}

Activity B (call some native method) is simply overriding the `onConfigurationChange`

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); 
}
```

in Manifest file

```
<activity
android:name=.B"
android:configChanges="locale|screenlayout|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screensize">
```

Comment: Please edit your question and make it readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
android:name=".B"
android:configChanges="locale|screenlayout|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screensize"
android:launchmode="SingleTask">
```

Single task will prevent your More than one instance.

Comment: i have used it but forget to mention any other solution